# Query Optimalization PostgreSQL (GreenPlum). Grouping based on Top 5 Rank Results

Tags: sql, query-optimization, rank, greenplum

Yo Guys i have this query to populate data

```
    insert into cem_summary_hourly_dly_sum_fct_20180805_x
select 
    trx_dt_sk_id,
    month_sk_id,
    sbscrptn_ek_id, 
    msisdn, 
    hours, 
    string_agg((case when res.seqnum <= 5 then category_name end), '|') as category_name,
    string_agg((case when res.seqnum <= 5 then application_name end), '|') as application_name,
    string_agg((case when res.seqnum <= 5 then browser_name end), '|') as browser_name,
    string_agg((case when res.seqnum <= 5 then os_name end), '|') as os_name,
    string_agg((case when res.seqnum <= 5 then volume_total_mb::character varying end), '|') as volume_mb_split,
    string_agg((case when res.seqnum <= 5 then activity_sec::character varying end), '|') as active_sec_split,
    sum(coalesce(volume_in, 0)) as volume_in,
    sum(coalesce(volume_out, 0)) as volume_out,
    sum(coalesce(volume_total_mb, 0)) as volume_total_mb,
    sum(coalesce(activity_sec, 0)) as activity_sec
    from (
select 
    trx_dt_sk_id,
    month_sk_id,
    sbscrptn_ek_id,
    msisdn,
    hours,
    category_name,
    application_name,
    browser_name,
    os_name,
    rank() over (partition by hours order by sum(volume_total_mb) desc) as seqnum,
    sum(coalesce(volume_in, 0)) as volume_in,
    sum(coalesce(volume_out, 0)) as volume_out,
    sum(coalesce(volume_total_mb, 0)) as volume_total_mb,
    sum(coalesce(activity_sec, 0)) as activity_sec
from dwh.cem_summary_hourly_dly_fct_1_prt_20180805 src
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ) res
group by 1,2,3,4,5;
```

so basically i do the grouping on sub query and give them rank. and then i retrieve the result when the rank is <= 5 (top 5). this query works, but takes long time (our one day data for this table is around 3 billions of data), it can take more than an hour.

i use another methods (create the grouping on temp table and then retrieve the result) but doesn't make any differences.

any suggestion to make this query run faster?

## UPDATE

here is the explain query result

```
    "Gather Motion 64:1  (slice2; segments: 64)  (cost=1902258144.94..1916188904.50 rows=30284260 width=492)"
    "  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1902258144.94..1916188904.50 rows=473192 width=492)"
    "        Group By: res.trx_dt_sk_id, res.month_sk_id, res.sbscrptn_ek_id, res.msisdn, res.hours"
    "        ->  Sort  (cost=1902258144.94..1903015251.44 rows=4731916 width=1180)"
    "              Sort Key: res.trx_dt_sk_id, res.month_sk_id, res.sbscrptn_ek_id, res.msisdn, res.hours"
    "              ->  Subquery Scan res  (cost=1279332227.27..1284631972.75 rows=4731916 width=1180)"
    "                    ->  Window  (cost=1279332227.27..1281603546.76 rows=4731916 width=1204)"
    "                          Partition By: src.hours"
    "                          Order By: (sum(src.volume_total_mb))"
    "                          ->  Sort  (cost=1279332227.27..1280089333.76 rows=4731916 width=1204)"
    "                                Sort Key: src.hours, (sum(src.volume_total_mb))"
    "                                ->  Redistribute Motion 64:64  (slice1; segments: 64)  (cost=391004281.95..650282943.07 rows=4731916 width=1204)"
    "                                      Hash Key: src.hours"
    "                                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=391004281.95..641197665.10 rows=4731916 width=1204)"
    "                                            Group By: src.trx_dt_sk_id, src.month_sk_id, src.sbscrptn_ek_id, src.msisdn, src.hours, src.category_name, src.application_name, src.browser_name, src.os_name"
    "                                            ->  Append-only Columnar Scan on cem_summary_hourly_dly_fct_1_prt_20180805 src  (cost=0.00..41629947.84 rows=47319156 width=104)"
    "Settings:  optimizer=off"
    "Optimizer status: legacy query optimizer"
```

some information: the table size is around 60GB. current process takes time more than one hour and we expect to be finished around 15 minutes.

Comment: Post the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: @eurotrash added the explain result. cheers

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Hi, i added explain result and some informations.

Comment: Not related to your problem. But you dont need `COALESCE` for `SUM`  Null values are ignored.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b104/1

Answer (score -1):

I can't give you a definitive answer, so I will give you some tips.

First build your query for steps and check the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and time after each step. When you found the moment times increase too much you look into that with more detail.

For the inner select you can try with a composite index including all those 9 field to help that grouping process.

Also you need one index for `hours` to help the rank function.

Again test one step each time, first create the select, add a field, add group by, add aggregated function, add rank() and if you see an increase in time add one index.

Comment: Indexes do not work the same in Greenplum (or at all in some cases) - FYI. See: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/590/admin_guide/ddl/ddl-index.html

Comment: @Nicarus In that case shouldnt you provide your own answer? I just try to give OP some guidelines.